# How to pass variable/string from a button to appscript function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom data validation dropdown and I wanted to set/select its value using a button to call the script.

```
function select(red) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B4').setValue(red);
}
```

Is there a way to pass a variable (red) from clicking a red button? `select(red)` cannot be found when I assign it but `select` only works.

I get this error :

> Script function select(red) could not be found

Comment: In the current stage, unfortunately, when a button on Spreadsheet is clicked, the variable for each button cannot be given. In your script, when `select(red)` is run by clicking the button, `red` is `undefined`. I think that the reason for your issue is this. So in your situation, how about preparing the functions for each button? But if this is not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike after searching for 2 hours, just saw that this one is possible. I just need to do it the hard way by creating one function each button and then pass the parameter. thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will help users who have the same issue.